# How does Entity Framework entity loading work?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I've been playing around with making my own Entity Framework (for personal projects and out of curiosity on what making something like this would take).

While I was doing Entity Framework performance tests with a data table with 700k rows and 5 columns (named `MassData`), I ran into something peculiar issues that I'm hoping someone could explain to me.

Running the following test:

```
var Context = new EntityFameworkContext();

var first = Context.MassData.Where(x => x.Id == 1);

var firstFifty = Context.MassData.Where(x => x.Id < 50).ToArray();
```

The context creation takes 35ms, getting `first` takes about 215ms and getting `firstFifty` takes 14ms.

Removing `'first'`, getting `'firstFifty'` takes about 210ms.

The results were the same if I switch the `'first'` query with a `Where()` that selects everything (still with no iteration).

My first thought, was that this was some case of loading the lazy data in the `DbSet`, with the first query enumerating data the next one accesses (even though the first one doesn't iterate through anything). This would kind of explain why the first always takes a minimum of 200ms regardless of the query, while the second runs as fast as if no database connection was even involved (the 'firstFifty' takes 25ms minimum to run as an SQL query, more than the 15ms I'm seeing here).

Except loading all of `MassData` takes 5 seconds. Just reading it takes about 2,5. So it can't be loading everything, but it's clearly loading more than the first query requires. So obviously I'm missing something.

Would anyone happen to have an explanation for why the

```
var first = Context.MassData.Where(x => x.Id == 1);
```

query speeds up the

```
var firstFifty = Context.MassData.Where(x => x.Id < 50).ToArray();
```

query?

---

**EDIT:**

Turns out, it really had nothing to do with lazy loading at all. The first query opens the connection and (I presume) does and stores the validation of the entity type against the database table. The second query then doesn't have to open the connection or do much if any validation, in which case the duration of the second query matches up, and everything makes sense.

---

**EDIT 2:**

Modified title to better match what the question ended up really being about (How does lazy-loading work => how does entity loading work).

Comment: None of this has to do with lazy loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're still loading the Entity Type and the prerequisites of it. Regardless of what you're trying to query. Lambda expression for EF still is SQL, with the conversion from Lambda to String clauses and statements. So the first slowness is not from the Query but from the EF Initial set up.

Remember, You're still creating an Instance of the EF so it will eat up some runtime process. Then the rest is Query Fetching time. This is unavoidable process of-course because of the CLR process.

So, Generally. The Second Query is ready for the Query since in your Model where you set up the EF is still on use, But when the Garbage collection decides that it is not going to be used anywhere, then your query for the next session will be slower at the begin Init for EF. "MEANING YOUR CONNECTION FROM THE DB IS STILL OPEN" as easy as that.

Comment: "MEANING YOUR CONNECTION FROM THE DB IS STILL OPEN" this hadn't occurred to me, and you're correct. Using SqlDataReader, without measuring the time it takes to open the connection, reading the results and mapping them takes 13ms, about the same amount of time EF takes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are tools to show sql server activity, so you do not have to guess (for example sql profiler for microsoft sql server). But the lag on first query has probably nothing to do with database, it is just EF internal initialization. EF is notoriously lazy.